# Spring declare component in xml

Tags: java, mysql, xml, spring-mvc, datasource

I am mostly using `@Autowired` and `@Component` annotations in my project. However, I am going to use `DataSource` class for database actions.

So, I use this is in my **dispatcher-servlet.xml** :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/market"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

In my dao class, My setter for the `dataSource` is :

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

}
```

However this is not doing the trick. My `jdbcTemplateObject` is `null`.

If I dont use "context:component scan ..." and use classical spring beans instead, without utilizing `@Autowired` annotation, all works good.

I can use my database. However, I dont want to declare all the beans one by one in my xml file. As the project grows, it is not going to be practical. How can I solve this problem ? Is it possible to declare `dataSource` in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` as component, so `@Autowired` works on dataSource ?

Comment: When you use `@Autowired` on fields Spring will look for dependencies and inject them right there there is no point if setter method here.

Comment: Spring will do that you do not need a setter. You can use jdbctemplate in xml and autowire it.

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not know I did not need a setter. How can it set it without a setter though ?

Comment: Enter it as an answer so I can label it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@Autowired` on fields `Spring` will look for `dependencies` and inject them right there there is no point if setter method here.

You do not need to worry about how spring is going to inject the dependency. It will take care of complete life cycle.

For more on `Spring's` Dependecy Injection visit [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm) link.

Answer (score 0):

You have annotated the field with `@Autowired` which tells spring to inject the dependency directly into the field. If you really want to use the setter annotate the setter with `@Autowired` instead of the field.

```
@Autowired
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds) { ... }
```

However I strongly suggest to not create a `JdbcTemplate` for each bean that needs one (it is quite heavy to create). The `JdbcTemplate` is a thread-safe object, once constructed. So instead of creating a new one for each bean that needs one (in the `setDataSource` method) just create a single `JdbcTemplate`and inject that.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Then in your dao.

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

Or what I like to do..

```
private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public YourRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
}
```

This way you cannot construct an illegal object, whereas with setter based injection you could. While maintaining the possibility to inject one for testing purposes.

Another note, the `DriverManagerDataSource` is nice for testing but not for production usage, for that use a real connection pool like [HikariCP](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) or [Tomcat JDBC](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).